# why I am getting an ValueError?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, valueerror

I am working on a CSV file.
I wrote a linear regression algorithm below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\asrivastava\Desktop\Python tutorials\Udemy data set machine leanring\Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder\Part 2 - Regression\Section 4 - Simple Linear Regression\Simple_Linear_Regression\Salary_Data.csv")

X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,1].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
print dataset
print X
print y

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size=1/3,random_state=0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor=LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)

#predicting the test set results
y_pred= regressor.predict(X_test)

(plt.scatter(X_train,y_train,color="red"))
(plt.plot(X_train,regressor.predict(X_train),color="blue"))
(plt.title("Salary vs Experince (Training set)"))
(plt.xlabel("Years of Experience"))
(plt.ylabel("Salary"))
plt.show()
```

here is the dataset

```
   YearsExperience    Salary
0               1.1   39343.0
1               1.3   46205.0
2               1.5   37731.0
3               2.0   43525.0
4               2.2   39891.0
5               2.9   56642.0
6               3.0   60150.0
7               3.2   54445.0
8               3.2   64445.0
9               3.7   57189.0
10              3.9   63218.0
11              4.0   55794.0
12              4.0   56957.0
13              4.1   57081.0
14              4.5   61111.0
15              4.9   67938.0
16              5.1   66029.0
17              5.3   83088.0
18              5.9   81363.0
19              6.0   93940.0
20              6.8   91738.0
21              7.1   98273.0
22              7.9  101302.0
23              8.2  113812.0
24              8.7  109431.0
25              9.0  105582.0
26              9.5  116969.0
27              9.6  112635.0
28             10.3  122391.0
29             10.5  121872.0
```

Comment: Do you know which line(s) of your code are throwing the [value] error?

Comment: The posted data set does not appear to be CSV file format, would you please check?

Answer (score 0):

The ValueError can be originating from

> (plt.scatter(X_train,y_train,color="red"))

We would be getting this if there is a mismatch in the shape of X_train and y_train.
Please check if X_train.shape and y_train.shape are in same vector form.

We can still make the code work by creating a scatterplot between specific column of X_train and y_train
eg.

> (plt.scatter(X_train.iloc[:,1],y_train,color="red"))